# XML, XML Stylesheets XQuery: book and development environment

Tags: xsd, stylesheet, xquery, development-environment

I'm completely new to XML Schema, XML Stylesheets and XQuery.

To me, XML is just a text file just containing tags and values. I know that much, lol.

I just got a [homework](http://sir-lab.usc.edu/cs585/CS585_fall_2009_assignment3.pdf) asking us to design simple XML Schemas, and also applying Stylesheets and XQuery.

Could anyone please point me to:

1. "Best" books/resources (based on your experience) that would teach me XML Schema, XML Stylesheet, and XQuery. (Would be awesome if it's example-driven since I learn best by doing).
2. What development environment (IDE, tools) that would allow me to solve the homework in the most productive way.

I know it's a school assignment, but I want to do the assignment like how professionals do it so I can gain a lot from the assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, as for the tools, these probably could do (each website also has resources (videos/tutorials) on how to use their tools)

- [Stylus Studio](http://www.stylusstudio.com/)
- [oXygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/)
- [Altova](http://www.altova.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The best place to learn about XML schemas is the [W3Schools site](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/default.asp).

Same for [XSL-T stylesheets](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/).

Go to the [source](http://jquery.com/) for jQuery.

I think [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/free_java_ide.html) is the best IDE for this, but that's pure Java.  The community edition includes XML features, but I'm not sure exactly what you're after.  XSL-T is best done by hand the first time.

Comment: is jQuery the same as XQuery? Would it be compatible with "Qexo"? (that's what they said they are going to use to test our work--though I dont know yet what it is.)

Comment: if you can recommend professional tools that's okay too..as long as they have free trial version.

Comment: No, jQuery != XQuery.  jQuery is a JavaScript library for web development, and XQuery "...is to XML what SQL is to database tables..."  See http://www.w3schools.com/xquery/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

I was looking around on Stackoverflow, and came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35790/what-xml-books-do-you-recommend). I like the suggestion of the post's chosen answer. I took a look at the book on Amazon, and its table of contents seems to show me the application of XML.

Answer (score 0):

This [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471791199) is probably is also good. Seems like it walks you through XML design.

Also, this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471777773) also covers tools! (check the table of contents)